# I want to group data in a list with missing values as delimiter

Tags: python, list

I have a sample data like this:

```
data = [1,2,3,nan,nan,nan,4,5,6,nan,nan,7,nan,8,9]
```

I want results like this:

```
group1 = [1,2,3]
```

```
group2 = [4,5,6]
```

```
group3 = [7]
```

```
group4 = [8,9]
```

But in fact I have a lot of information.
can you help me ?

Comment: What kind of library are you using? ```nan``` is not a standard python type. What's your attempt to solve this so far?

Comment: I want to extract numbers from the list. `nan`  may represent the unwanted. I have defined it as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `nan` is the `math.nan` type, this would be a way of doing it. If it's not, you can just use a different comparison when it checks if the element is `nan`. This approach would return a list of lists.

```
from math import isnan, nan

data = [1,2,3,nan,nan,4,5,6,nan,nan,7,nan,8,9]

current_list = []
res = []
for ele in data:
    if not isnan(ele): # Your comparison here
        current_list.append(ele)
    else:
        if current_list:
            res.append(current_list)
            current_list = []
if current_list:
    res.append(current_list)
print(res)
>>> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7], [8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Every time you want to group something, you probably want to go for `itertools.groupby` or `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from math import nan

data = [1, 2, 3, nan, nan, nan, 4, 5, 6, nan, nan, 7, nan, 8, 9]

from itertools import groupby

g = groupby(data, key=type)  # group by type of the data, int != float

groups = [list(a[1]) for a in g if a[0] != float]  

print(groups)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7], [8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 1):

With [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
from functools import reduce

nan = None
data = [1,2,3,nan,nan,nan,4,5,6,nan,nan,7,nan,8,9]

def myReducer(x, y):
    if y!= nan:
        x[-1].append(y)
    else:
        if x[-1] != []:
            x.append([])
    return x

reduce(myReducer, data, [[]])
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7], [8, 9]]
```

Note: the array (iterable) is **not** the first argument of reduce, the reducer function is.