# Group data in a list with missing values as delimeter

Tags: python, list

I have an extended question following this question: [I want to group data in a list with missing values as delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70877026/i-want-to-group-data-in-a-list-with-missing-values-as-delimiter).

For example I have a list like this:

```
data = [1, 2, 3, nan, nan, nan, 4, 5, 6, nan, nan, 7, nan, 8, 9, nan, 0, 0, 'hello']
```

```
from math import nan

data = [1, 2, 3, nan, nan, nan, 4, 5, 6, nan, nan, 7, nan, 8, 9, nan, 0, 0, 'hello']

from itertools import groupby

g = groupby(data, key=type)  # group by type of the data, int != float

groups = [list(a[1]) for a in g if a[0] != float]  

print(groups)
```

I got this results:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7], [8, 9], [0, 0], ['hello']]
```

Expected results:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7], [8, 9], [0, 0, 'hello']]
```

What I have tried by adjusting the **groups** variable but it did not work:

```
groups = [list(a[1]) for a in g if a[0] != float or a[0] == str]
```

How can I adjust this in order to mix the value between integer and string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `isinstance()` in `groupby` key function:

```py
from itertools import groupby

g = groupby(data, key=lambda v: isinstance(v, float))
groups = [list(a[1]) for a in g if not a[0]]
print(groups)
```

Prints:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7], [8, 9], [0, 0, 'hello']]
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit for **key** variable?

Comment: `math.isnan` might be better than `isinstance`/`float` ;)

Comment: @Erwin `isinstance(v, float)` returns `True` is variable `v` is of type `float` (for `nan` it returns `True`)

Comment: @mozway `math.isnan` doesn't work well with Strings in this case.

Comment: But `lambda v: v is nan` should work well.

Comment: @thefourtheye good point I hadn't seen the string, then I guess `not (isinstance(v, float) and math.isnan(v))` and inverting the condition for the filter

Answer (score 0):

```
from math import nan
data = [1, 2, 3, nan, nan, nan, 4, 5, 6, nan, nan, 7, nan, 8, 9, nan, 0, 0, 'hello']

result = [[]]

for value in data:
    if value is not nan:
        result[-1].append(value)
    else:
        if result[-1]:
            result.append([])
if not result[-1]:
    del result[-1]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `groupby` + `filter`

```
In [1]: list(filter(lambda x: x[0] is not nan, [list(l) for _, l in groupby(data, key=lambda x: x is nan)]))
Out[1]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7], [8, 9], [0, 0, 'hello']]
```